Strange water leak on front porch – how to find the source?
A water leak has appeared on my front porch, right under the railing. See the pictures. As you can see in the pictures, only this one spot on the railing is dripping water—everything else in that area is bone dry. Based on reviewing my cameras, the puddle formed at around 1:28 pm today. No one was on the property around that time. I have never seen any water leak like this and I’m not sure how to go about finding the source.
Some more context:
Yesterday we had some heavy rains, but today is sunny and dry. This morning at 8 am my lawn maintenance company came to apply a liquid fertilizer treatment to the lawn, but the techician did not spray on the porch and no puddle was present throughout the morning.
Roof leak?
Above this porch is my lower roof, which had some severely damaged shingles, damaged by the builder and/or subcontractors who built the home about two years ago. I had that fixed by a roofer about a year ago. He replaced shingles and underlayment for large section of the lower roof. Could it be possible that there’s water leaking from that roof dripping down to the lower railing of the porch? I’ve never seen any signs of a leak from that area before.
Any thoughts or ideas about how to find the source of this water? Should I even be worried about this?




Update: We had some more rain the other day and the water leak re-appeared. I noticed that there is some water leaking in another location on the porch. Take a look at the pictures below. The railing has become disconnected in one part. With wind blowing in the right direction, rain water could get in there and then leak out slowly. That seems to me to be the best explanation because I didn’t find any evidence of a leak anywhere else. Thanks to everyone who commented and shared their advice.



My guess is some rain water seeped into the bottom rail of the railing and it started to drip out the end after some time.

That whole think looks to me made out of hollow pieces, it could be coming from anywhere above

Water will follow along a surface. Likely, as @Jasen states, it came from above and followed along that support-post's interior.

The posts are definitely supporting the roof above. They cannot be hollow. However the railing is absolutely hollow.

they might not be wood, although the do look rather like wood, especially the cracks in the baseboard mitres, and the over-painting at the rail ends,

Glad you found that. Please write it up as an answer (down below) instead of editing it into the question itself (then click the check mark when the system lets you - 24 hours, I think). This will help people in the future discover an answer without even having to ask.
